How to @mention when creating a FeedItem record via Flow?
I am having an issue when trying to create a FeedItem record via Flow, where I need to @mention the full name of the OwnerId of the Lead record which triggered the flow. However, when the FeedItem post is created, the value after the @ is blank.

I am using a Text Template variable, and I've tried multiple different text formats, but nothing seems to work. I can't get the Name of the user to display on the post. (I am retrieving the User's Name from a Get Records to the User object, since if I use the OwnerId field from Lead, it would only display the literal ID; and if I try to access the Name directly through the OwnerId (User) relationship field from Lead, I get an error).
Ps. The reason why I am not using a regular Post to Chatter action element instead is because I need to post this as an Integration User.
Any thoughts or tips on how to solve this are very much appreciated!
Thank you!

Does this answer your question? Flow - Create Chatter @ Mention Post

For the at-mention into the body follow these steps:

Add square brackets [ ] around the merge field, like this: [{!$Record.Owner.Name}]
Add an @ symbol at the beginning and a comma at the end, like this: @[{!Record.Owner.Name}],
- When followed by a value enclosed in square brackets, the @ symbol inserts the value as a mention

